# How to hide user dashboard details in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to hide details from the backend user (not admin) WordPress dashboard like `Recently Published` `From our Blog` `WordPress Events and News` `Admin Colour Scheme` `Help` `Activity` `Screen Options`

I haven't been able to locate the html (php/javascript?) for any of it but located some html for the colour scheme picker as follows:

```
<h2>Personal Options</h2>
<table class="form-table">
<tr class="user-admin-color-wrap">
<th scope="row">Admin Color Scheme</th>
<td>
<fieldset id="color-picker" class="scheme-list">
<legend class="screen-reader-text"><span>Admin Color Scheme</span>. 
</legend>
<input type="hidden" id="color-nonce" name="color-nonce" 
value="98ec68455d" /><div class="color-option selected">
<input name="admin_color" id="admin_color_fresh" type="radio" 
value="fresh" class="tog"  checked='checked' />
<input type="hidden" class="css_url" value="" />
<input type="hidden" class="icon_colors" value="{&quot;icons&quot;:  
{&quot;base&quot;:&quot;#a0a5aa&quot;, 
&quot;focus&quot;:&quot;#00a0d2&quot;,&quot;
current&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;}}" />
<label for="admin_color_fresh">Default</label>
<table class="color-palette">
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #222">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="background-color: #333">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="background-color: #0073aa">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="background-color: #00a0d2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="color-option ">
<input name="admin_color" id="admin_color_light" type="radio" 
value="light" class="tog"  />
<input type="hidden" class="css_url" value="https://adsler.co.uk/wp- 
admin/css/colors/light/colors.min.css" />
<input type="hidden" class="icon_colors" value="{&quot;icons&quot;:  
{&quot;base&quot;:&quot;#999&quot;,&quot;focus&quot;
:&quot;#ccc&quot;,&quot;current&quot;:&quot;#ccc&quot;}}" />
<label for="admin_color_light">Light</label>
<table class="color-palette">
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #e5e5e5">&nbsp;</td>
```

Tried css:

```
 #tab-panel-overview {visibility: hidden;} 

.help-tab-content active {visibility: hidden;} 

.form-table {visibility:hidden; display:none;} 


.user-admin-color-wrap {visibility: hidden; display: none;}
```

Also tried:

```
.scheme-list {visibility:hidden;}
```

Nothing.[image][image]

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of what you want taken out? The question is slightly confusing as you talk of dashboard widgets then say not admin. Thanks. I will respond accordingly.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. So as you may know, WordPress uses different user roles `subscriber` `Editor` etc. The `Admin` user role is exclusively for the owner /manager of the site. This gives you complete overview of everything and allows you to customise / approve etc whatever other users are doing. I don't mind what this looks like as long as it has everything in it.....

Comment: With the other user roles, however, there is a reduced dashboard. They can only see certain things, mainly only the things you need to see and can only edit your own posts/profile as well as post in specific catagories, namely jobs, dating, events. When a user, `the role in this case is subscriber` (but I'd like to hide the details mentioned above for all users except admin) logs in to the site, they have their reduced menu, but on the home screen they see all the stuff mentioned above which I don't want - `colour picker to define admin screen color` WordPress Blog` etc. They don't need it

Comment: If they only option is to hide this stuff for admin role too, I'd still be keen to see what it is... Thanks

Comment: How do I attach screenshot?

Comment: For example, I want to keep `screen options` for admin preferably....

Comment: You can see site here if helps: https://adsler.co.uk

Comment: @omukiguy please see screenshots..

Comment: I have added the solution. Let me know if you have any other left intact but needs removal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this through a plugin or add the code to your functions.php. 
This is tested and will work.See screenshot attached

```
function stackinnerflow_remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    // Remove At a glance
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now']);
    // Remove Activity
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_activity']);
    // Remove News and Events
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']);
}

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'stackinnerflow_remove_dashboard_widgets' );

// removes the `profile.php` admin color scheme options
remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );

// Remove thanks WP
add_action('admin_head', 'stackinnerflow_footer_remove');

function stackinnerflow_footer_remove() {
  echo '<style>
              #footer-thankyou,
              #footer-upgrade {
                  display:none;
              } 
        </style>';
}

// remove the Help Tab use

add_action('admin_head', 'stackinnerflow_remove_help_tabs');
function stackinnerflow_remove_help_tabs() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    $screen->remove_help_tabs();
}

//remove the Screen Options Tab
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', '__return_false');
```

If your wrap all the code for users below the level of administrator capabilities any user as editor or lower will not see this apart from the administrators.

`if (current_user_can('editor')) {}`

If you want to loop over a number of other capabilities, check this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131814/if-the-current-user-is-an-administrator-or-editor

[image]

Comment: Can you remove the if condition and check if that’s what you want?

Comment: Yes and the last } down at the bottom

Comment: So removed exactly `if (current_user_can('editor'))` and `}` at the bottom and site's not working..

Comment: Because you left { where the if condition was.

Comment: OK. Removed the first `{` to and now it's working.. Some things have gone too but `from our blog` `screen options` `thank you for creating with WordPress etc` and `help` are still there

Comment: Kindly let me know which version of WP that you are using.

Comment: Hi. I don't know because I tried your new code and everything has gone... :-) thanks, except for `from our blog`

Comment: If you don't know that's fine and I can mark correct? Thanks

Comment: The version is usually in the bottom right hand corner but won't show now with that code you have applied. If it the solution is helpful. Don't forget to upvote if this is the solution for another person to benefit from the answer.

Comment: That's great. Thanks omukiguy. And if you do find a way to remove Wp blog, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Also, what function does my Stack Overflow username `stackinnerflow`, serve in the code? Thanks.

Comment: It makes the functions names unique so you don’t get any conflicts. Simply rename the functions

Comment: Oh, I see. Great. Thanks.

Comment: Still trying to figure out this blog removal stuff. Tried     `// Remove From our blog
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']);` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You mean the admin dashboard widgets?
You can hide them with following wordpress action.

```
function remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_incoming_links']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_drafts']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_comments']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary']);

}

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets' );
```

Comment: Please see comments above. Is that what your answer does? Thanks.

Comment: Also, just want to hide the things listed above, preferably only for users, not admin...

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of the dashboard page details you want to hide?

Comment: You can do that by getting user role using wp_get_current_user function.

Comment: How do I do that?-screenshot?

Comment: add above code in functions.php of current activated theme